# Duplicate row based on date difference

Tags: sql, oracle, recursive-query

help needed. I have a set of data from oracle import to tableau for calculation. But in order to do that, i need to duplicate charts as shown in table below. For example, if there is date diff between start and end, then i need to duplicate it and assign with code 0,1 depend on how many date differences. The purpose is i need to use this function in Tableau for time interval calculation. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Paste your actual data and expected results and not the image.

Comment: @mohdatif sorry, my laptop was block on file sharing due to company privacy policy. I cant upload any files, that’s why i can only create a dummy simple table and snapshot like above. Really apologise for this inconveniences

Answer (score 3):

Pregenerate codes up to max possible value and join original table to code series so that number of row duplications is determined by difference between dates on particular row:

```sql
with t (s,e) as (
  select timestamp '2020-08-16 18:30:00', timestamp '2020-08-16 20:00:00' from dual union all
  select timestamp '2020-08-17 08:00:00', timestamp '2020-08-18 08:00:00' from dual union all
  select timestamp '2020-08-19 08:00:00', timestamp '2020-08-19 00:00:00' from dual union all
  select timestamp '2020-08-20 10:00:00', timestamp '2020-08-22 03:00:00' from dual
), series (code) as (
  select level - 1 from dual connect by level <= (select count(*) from t)
)
select t.*, series.code
from t
join series on trunc(e) - trunc(s) >= series.code
order by s,code;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But how can i modify this code if my database is refresh every hourly, and the time stamp is keep changing hourly? Sorry, i still learning sql so this code is quite complicated for me

Comment: “..join original table to code series so that number of row duplications is determined by difference between dates on particular row..” 

 which line of code does above function?

Comment: ad 1st comment: from your sample input it seems to me that timestamp does not matter at all. So if timestamp has some influence on query result, define better sample input which covers interesting cases. Ad 2nd comment: the CTE `series` is just sequence of numbers 0,1,2,3,... bounded by maximum possible code number (i.e. if all timestamps belonged to same date). To understand main query, try to `select trunc(e)-trunc(s)` separately. You'll find the timestamps have the values 0,1,0,2. So first timestamp joins with series CTE only on single row, second timestamp on two rows etc.